# determine distribution by finding the moment generating function

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis, Rice, Chapter 4, Problem 92

$\theta$ is Gamma($\lambda,\alpha$) distributed, $X|\theta$ follows a Poisson($\theta$) distribution. Wanted: the unconditional distribution of $\alpha + X$.

Attempt:
$M_{\alpha+X}(t) = e^{\alpha t}E(E(e^{tX}|\theta)) = e^{\alpha t}E(M_{X|\theta}(t)) = e^{\alpha t}E(e^{\theta(e^t-1)}) = e^{\alpha t}M_{\theta}(e^t-1) = \left(\frac{\lambda e^t}{(\lambda-e^t+1)}\right)^\alpha$

Can someone help me along? How to identify to which distribution the mgf belongs?

Comment: Sure. To carry on, one needs $M_\theta(e^t-1)$, so, what is $M_\theta$?

Comment: Use the expansion of $(1-u)^{-\alpha}$ for $u=e^t/(\lambda+1)$.

Comment: No, the *expansion* is something like $$\frac1{(1-u)^\alpha}=\sum_nc_nu^n.$$

Comment: ((Several comments by the OP now deleted.))

Answer (score 1):

The OP arrived at the expansion $$M_{\alpha+X}(t)=E(\mathrm e^{t(\alpha+X)})=\left(\frac{\lambda e^t}{\lambda-e^t+1}\right)^\alpha.$$ Factoring the constant factor and the factor involving a power of $\mathrm e^t$, and using the expansion $$\frac1{(1-u)^\alpha}=\sum_{k\geqslant0}{\alpha+k-1\choose k}u^k,$$ for the argument $$u=\frac{\mathrm e^t}{\lambda+1},$$ this is also
$$
M_{\alpha+X}(t)=\left(\frac{\lambda \mathrm e^t}{\lambda+1}\right)^\alpha\frac1{(1-u)^\alpha}=\left(\frac{\lambda \mathrm e^t}{\lambda+1}\right)^\alpha\sum_{k\geqslant0}{\alpha+k-1\choose k}\left(\frac{\mathrm e^t}{\lambda+1}\right)^k.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k\geqslant0}\mathrm e^{t(\alpha+k)}P(X=k)=\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}\right)^\alpha\sum_{k\geqslant0}{\alpha+k-1\choose k}\left(\frac1{\lambda+1}\right)^k\mathrm e^{t(\alpha+k)},$$
and, by identification, for every $k\geqslant0$,
$$P(X=k)=P(\alpha+X=\alpha+k)=\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}\right)^\alpha{\alpha+k-1\choose k}\left(\frac1{\lambda+1}\right)^k.$$ Thus, the distribution of $X$ is [negative binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) $(\alpha;p)$, with $$p=\frac1{\lambda+1}.$$

Comment: Is the Edit enough to dispel your trouble?

Comment: Sorry but I am not following: what you call a factorization is simply getting rid of obvious factors, that is, a constant factor and an exponential, then the remaining term happens to have a known series expansion, hence we are done.

Comment: I don't see that it is obvious :-/ I mean, in both factors there is the exponential, in both is λ. So I struggle to see how to come up with this..nor do I know how to "find" those two factors, while I can verify it to hold.

Comment: First, $\lambda$ is a constant hence I fail to see why you mention it. Second, as already said, $e^{ct}$ is the MGF of the constant $c$ hence, $e^{ct}M_Y(t)$ is simply $M_{c+Y}(t)$, for every constant $c$ and every random variable $Y$. Finally, one needs to recognize that the $(1-u)^{-a}$ factor is a well known series. (As an aside, I find your repeated comment complaining that this is not "obvious", slightly odd: yes, if one knows nothing about nothing, solving anything can be less than obvious. Why would you expect otherwise?)

Comment: ((Several comments by the OP now deleted. What is happening exactly?))